# ¿Cómo hacer que un botón haga dos cosas?

Tags: vb.net

Estoy haciendo este código que al momento de presionarle `Start` la barra de progreso empieza a cargar. La puedo detener y reiniciar, pero deseo que al momento de presionarle al botón de `Stop` este diga `Continue` y al presionar `Continue` la barra siga cargando donde se quedó y nuevamente vuelva el texto del botón a su estado original que era `Stop`.

Le intenté poner un `if` en el botón 3 que es el botón de `Stop`, pero me marca error.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Timer1.Start()
        Label1.Text = "ON"
    End Sub

    Private Sub ProgressBar1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ProgressBar1.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        ProgressBar1.Increment(1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Timer1.Stop()
        Button3.Text = "Continue"

        If Button3.Click = True Then

            Timer1.Start()

        End If

        Button3.Text = "Stop"

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        ProgressBar1.Value = 0
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Hola @Victor. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Cuando publique una pregunta con un código que te das error, deberías publicar el error exacto que te está dando y describir cómo se está comportando que no debería suceder. De esa forma, le facilitás la tarea a alguien que quiera ayudarte y lograrías mejores respuestas.

Comment: Cuando compilo el código y presiono el botón de Stop, detiene la barra de progreso y el texto del botón cambia a Continue hasta ahí funciona bien, pero cuando presiono el boton de Continue, la barra de progreso no vuelva a cargar

Answer (score 1):

La idea que tienes de una condición `IF` no es mala, pero me parece que necesitas una variable más que te permita determinar en qué estado quedó el botón la última vez que le hicistes click:

```
Private isButton3Stop As Boolean = True

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    If isButton3Stop Then
        isButton3Stop = False
        Timer1.Stop()
        Button3.Text = "Continue"
    Else
        isButton3Stop = True
        Timer1.Start()
        Button3.Text = "Stop"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución a tu problema debe ser utilizar una **variable,** o una **propiedad del objeto** en cuestión, para determinar en que "estado" se encuentra el boton. Vos usaste la propiedad  `Button3.Click = True` para determinar ello, solo que esa propiedad en el objeto **Button no existe**.

Más acertado podría ser utilizar como parámetro el texto del botón, y utilizar una sentencia **`Select Case`**.

```
// Teniendo en cuenta que el Button3 comienza con la propiedad .Text = "Start"
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
Select Case Button3.Text
Case "Start"
 Timer1.Start()
 Button3.Text = "Stop"
Case "Stop"
Timer1.Stop()
 Button3.Text = "Continue"
Case "Continue"
Timer1.Start()
 Button3.Text = "Stop"
End Select
```